# Keep-alive not working with v-if and slot

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I want to keep certain part of my component alive when `v-if="false"`
The part I want to keep alive contains a slot, and it doesn't work.
The component within the slot is still mounted every time the v-if changes.
Is it possible to keep it alive in some way?

```js
<div v-if="index === 1">
   <keep-alive >
      <div :key="tab.id">
         <slot></slot>
      </div>
   </keep-alive>
</div>
```

Comment: have you tried to move `keep-alive` one level upper, before the div with the `v-if`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `v-show` instead of `v-if`.  It will be rendered once, and then hidden when the expression is false.

I have only used `keep-alive` with `dynamic components`.